# index out of range C++/Qt

Tags: c++, qt

ASSERT failure in QList::operator[]: "index out of range", Why?

> ```
> QList<int>    tanksLevel;
> ......
> for(int i=0; i < 6; i++)
>    tanksLevel[i] = rand() %51;
> ```

Comment: Probably your index is out of range :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that `i >= tanksLevel.size()`. Check that. You may want to initialize your list with correct size first or use `QList::append` instead of `operator[]`.

Comment: How i can put six values to a tanksLevel ?

Comment: `QList<int> tanksLevel(6); //using contructor, or...`

`tanksLevel.resize(6); //after contruction, or...`

`for(...) tanksLevel.append(newValue); //appending new value after each iteration`